# time data did not match error in strptime

Tags: python

I'm converting a string into time object in python 2.4.

```
d1 = time.strptime(d2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%%')
```

Here d2 is `'2012-11-07 13:41:13.138807'`

I'm getting the following error.

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=2012-11-07 13:41:13.138807  fmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%%
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `.%f` to your string (Python 2.6+), which should handle the value (although it does not appear to be stored):

```
In [5]: import time

In [6]: d2 = '2012-11-07 13:41:13.138807'

In [7]: d1 = time.strptime(d2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

In [8]: d1
Out[8]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=13, tm_min=41, tm_sec=13, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=312, tm_isdst=-1)
```

The solution from @bradleyayers will accurately capture your microsecond value if needed, so if you need that, I would suggest using his way :)

Since the `%f` parameter for `datetime`/`time` isn't available pre-2.6, and if you don't need to capture the microseconds, you can try something like this (rough idea that splits on the period and takes the first element - could likely be optimized):

```
In [20]: import time

In [21]: d2 = '2012-11-07 13:41:13.138807'

In [22]: d2_noms = d2.split('.')[0]

In [23]: d1 = time.strptime(d2_noms, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

In [24]: d1
Out[24]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=13, tm_min=41, tm_sec=13, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=312, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: I'm getting "KeyError: 'f'". I'm using python 2.4

Comment: @thavan Ah, sorry, should have put the Python 2.6+ part in there. This is not ideal, but would modifying the string to strip out the microsecond portion be an option?

Comment: I don't need microseconds. Is it possible to omit that part?

Comment: @thavan Dropped in an edit - will that work in your situation?

Comment: No problem, happy it helps. If you ever do end up switching to Python 2.7, feel free to switch the check mark to @bradley.ayers - that is the best way to go about it for sure :)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in the last two characters in the string: `%%`

`%%` matches a `%` in the input. You want to match microseconds, [so you should use](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) `%f`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d2 = '2012-11-07 13:41:13.138807'
>>> datetime.strptime(d2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 7, 13, 41, 13, 138807)
```

Comment: datetime doesn't have strptime method.

Comment: @thavan the `datetime` module doesn't, but `datetime.datetime` does. See my import :)

Comment: I think the 2.4 part is throwing us both off :)

Comment: yes. AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'. May be because of python 2.4.

Comment: @bradley.ayers Haha, same here - I was very confused for a bit :) (+1 to you by the way)